# Scroll down to another page

Tags: jquery

Would like to know how to link to another page when scrolling down.

Reference
https://phase3.uk/

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you want to add another slide

Comment: In the example you gave, they are using a Javascript framework called Vue. It looks to me that the page isn't actually changing, they are just using the framework to modify the address bar and show/hide content

Comment: Also, FYI I would encourage you to post code that you have already attempted rather than posting with no code.

Answer (score 0):

Load a specific file when the scroll reaches a certain position

```js
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowOffset = $(this).scrollTop();
    var loadOffset = $("offset").offset().top;
    if (windowOffset > loadOffset) {
      $(".loadtags").load("locationOfLoadedFile");
    }
  });
```